# αF SMD resistor coding

Tags: resistors

Can somebody tell my what is the value of the resistor with αF SMD resistor coding as shown in figure below?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: that doesn't seem to be a resistor at all.

Comment: My money's on it being a polyfuse...

Comment: I'm not sure why @Berk's answer was deleted but it appears to be the correct answer- a 0.5A PTC. Link to datasheet: http://doc.aemchina.com/Catalog/PMS1206_series_Feb.2023.pdf   A similar link appears in a comment below.

Answer (score 4):

The product in the photo is [Gravity: Analog Current to Voltage Converter](https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Gravity__Analog_Current_to_Voltage_Converter_for_4~20mA_Application__SKU_SEN0262).

As for the components (\$\alpha F\$) in the question, I've checked the [schematic](https://github.com/DFRobot/Wiki/raw/master/SEN0262/res/%5BSEN0262%5D(V1.0)%20Schematic.pdf), they are shown as R2 and R5 but no details have been given.

Most likely they are protection elements: could be a fuse or even a resettable (PTC) fuse *(I'd prefer the latter, though, since the product is designed for 4-20mA.)*. They can even be from German company [Alpha-Therm](http://www.alpha-therm.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I think I've found the component info. 

It is a PTC !!! ref: http://www.comcraft.co.jp/products/aem/data/pptc.pdf